# symfony2 enable to find routing error for optional parameter

Tags: symfony

I would like to add a format to my route, but this error is appearing always:

```
No route found for "GET /ecomerce/0" (from "http://localhost/ecomerce/web/app_dev.php/ecomerce/")
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException
```

This is what I've tried

```
//<li> <a href='{{path('ecomerce_first',{'id':17})-'.html'}}'> First </a> </li>  

ecomerce_first:
    path: /{id}/first.{_format }
    defaults: { _controller: "EcomerceBundle:Default:firstTest" , _format: html }
    requirements: _format: html
    id: \d+
```

in the routing.yml of the EcomerceBundle

Comment: this is what i've tried

Comment: <li> <a href='{{path('ecomerce_first',{'id':17})-'.html'}}'> First </a> </li>                   in the base.html.twiig

Comment: ecomerce_first:
    path:     /{id}/first.{_format }
    defaults: { _controller: "EcomerceBundle:Default:firstTest" , _format: html }
    requirements:
        _format: html
        id: \d+                                                                                                                in the routing.yml of the EcomerceBundle

Comment: `/ecomerce/0` doesn't match the path declaration. The Twig snippet also doesn't look like valid format (specifically, `{'id':17})-'.html'` isn't valid concat, should be `{'id':17}) ~ '.html'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you want have url like this?

> /ecomerce/1/first.html

Try next solution:

```
<li> <a href='{{ path('ecomerce_first',{'id':17, '_format': 'html'})'}}'> First </a> </li>
```

PS: I noticed that here you have extra whitespace in {_format }

> path: /{id}/first.{_format }

try remove it

Comment: Welcome! I glad that could help you.
I'll be happy if you mark my answer ;)